# Vue and Chartjs - Running a simple example of vue-chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to use Chart.js with Vue.js and this is what I got it is compiling but I don't see anything displayed on the GUI.

This is my file DonutChart.vue:

```
<template>
 // NOT SURE IF SOMETHING SHOULD GO HERE
</template>

<script>
  import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'
  // import the component - chart you need

  export default Bar.extend({
    mounted () {
      // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
      this.renderChart({
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'News reports',
            backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc',
            data: [12, 20, 12, 18, 10, 6, 9, 32, 29, 19, 12, 11]
          }
        ]
      },)
    }
  });
</script>
```

This is the parent component, ´Usage.vue´:

```
<template>
      <h1>USAGE</h1>
      <st-donut-chart></st-donut-chart>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import Filter from './shared/filter/Filter';
  import DonutChart from './DonutChart'

  export default new Vue({
    name: 'st-usage',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    },
    components: {
      'st-filter': Filter,
      'st-donut-chart': DonutChart,
    }

  });
</script>
```

DonutChart.vue and Usage.vue are on the same directory:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

vue-chartjs author here.

Well it's a bit confusing for beginners. However `vue-chartjs` is utilizing `Vue.extend()`.

That's why you're have to extent the imported component.

### Step 1

- Create your own component and extend the base chart. This way you have more control over everything.

Your `DonutChart.vue` was nearly right. But you have to remove the `<template>`  from your component. Because of the Vue.extend() you're extending the base component. So you have access to the props, methods etc. defined there. However there is no way of extending `templates`. So if you let the `template` tag in your component, it will **overwrite** the template defined in the base chart, that you're extending. Thats why you can't see anything ;)

YourChart.vue:

```
<script>
  // Import the base chart
  import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

  // Extend it
  export default Bar.extend({
    props: ['chartdata', 'options'],
    mounted () {
      // Overwriting base render method with actual data and options
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }
  })
</script>
```

Now you have the Chart Component. You can put more login in there, of define some styles or options.

### Step 2

Import it and feed it the data.

Like you did :)

---

### Update

With version 3 of vue-chartjs the creation has changed. Now its more vue-like.

```
<script>
  // Import the base chart
  import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

  // Extend it
  export default {
    extends: Bar,
    props: ['chartdata', 'options'],
    mounted () {
      // Overwriting base render method with actual data and options
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Or you can use `mixins`

```
<script>
  // Import the base chart
  import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

  // Extend it
  export default {
    mixins: [Bar],
    props: ['chartdata', 'options'],
    mounted () {
      // Overwriting base render method with actual data and options
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So now I got it working:

```
  import DonutChart from './DonutChart'

  export default ({  //<= Notice change here
    name: 'st-usage',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    },
    components: {
      'st-filter': Filter,
      'line-example':LineExample,
      'st-donut-chart':DonutChart,
    }

  });
```

Comment: This answer will be more beneficial to future readers if you add some explanation on what you changed to get it to work.